# xargs oneliner to unzip files

Tags: bash, xargs

From the bash command line, I have to find all the zip files whose name matches a certain pattern in my system and then unzip them in my directory.

I would like to organize the unzipped files in subfolders, and I would like to choose my subfolders name with a custom naming convention based on the original zip files name (without using the full path).

I know that the **for** cycle works, anyway, as I'm learning xargs right now,  I would like to know if I can do the same thing in an xargs oneliner; something similar to:

```
locate -r "<zipped files regex>" | xargs -i -t "foldername=$(echo {} | sed 's/.*\///'); mkdir -p $folderName; unzip {} -d $folderName"
```

I get this message:

```
foldername={}; mkdir -p ; unzip {} -d
xargs: foldername={}; mkdir -p ; unzip {} -d : No such file or directory
```

Can you help me to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the current command? Also, can you provide an example of `<getFolderName from {}>` to make it reproducible?

Comment: Xargs passes everything to one single zip command and zip can handle only one zip-file at a time, so you should either use a for-loop or `find ... -exec`.

Comment: @SamiLaine Good point, but `xargs` has a `-n` (`--max-args`) option. Still, using `find` with `-exec` is more straightforward.

Comment: @Lev: for example  `locate -r ".*libs_j.*jar$" | xargs -i -t "foldername=$(echo {} | sed 's/.*\///'); mkdir -p folderName; unzip {} -d $folderName"`

Comment: @FrancescoS. You can [edit] the question to add more info. Also, providing the error message or other details of "not working" is always helpful. You have `-t`, it should print the commands it builds. Do they look correct?

Comment: @Lev: ok, I've modified the question. Anyway I'll give SamiLaine suggestion a try!

Comment: @LevLevitsky: I've added the output as suggested and it's not definitely correct! It seems that the curly braces inside the echo command are not correctly interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

The `echo {} | sed 's/.*\///'` that is within `$()` is executed before anything else, before xargs and before locate. So it is hard to do this with xargs. One way without using xargs:

```
locate -r [.]zip$ | \
   sed 's!.*/\([^/]*\)$!mkdir -p "\1"; unzip -n -d "\1" "&";!' | \
   sh 2> ERRORS
```

Comment: I didn't know this kind of usage for sed, absolutely smart solution! thx!

Comment: This effectively makes `sed` act as a smarter, more robust `xargs`

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU Parallel for improved readability and possibly speedup:

```
locate -r [.]zip$ | parallel "mkdir -p {/.}; cd {/.} && unzip {}"
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.